# Display a hyperlink in Visual Studio Output window using OutputDebugString()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I find it very useful to be able to include hyperlinks in the debug output of my test suite like this:

```
OutputDebugStringA("file://c:/path/index.html")
```

The above command prints the quoted URL to the output window as a hyperlink.  It can be CTRL-clicked and the specified HTML file will open in a new IDE tab.

In itself, this is very valuable.  However, my suite generates dozens of potentially useful HTML logfiles and during debugging the Output Window becomes a sea of blue escaped URLs.  I want to hide the URL and show some alternate CTRL-clickable text.  The following doesn't work but should illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
OutputDebugStringA("<a href=\"file://c:/path/index.html\">Index</a>")
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically at the mercy of however the output window is implemented; I'm guessing it's just hotting up things that look like URLs and probably doesn't support HTML.  Maybe you can develop a Visual Studio add-in that behaves similar to the output window that supports HTML.